# nosetests command shows error in powershell, what should i do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, nosetests

I am a newbie to python and learning python from **Zed A. shaw's book "Learn python the hard way" (3rd edition)**.

I am trying to run the `nosetests` command but it does nothing rather shows some error message (as shown in the screenshot attached).

[Link to the exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html)

Could you please help me out what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Error:

[image: error message]

Comment: Where is the `nosetest` executable on your computer?

Comment: ok, you are right. i was running it in the wrong directory. thanks  anyways. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP, he was running the command in the wrong directory.